# Directional statistics of a system that is more populated near equator

Tags: probability, geometry, statistics, vectors, random-variables

Can we mathematically express a distribution of uniaxially symmetric random vectors (like symmetric around the north pole) but more likely to point the equator. In the von Mises-Fisher distribution, random vectors are likely to point a specific direction but some systems may have vectors tend to be perpendicular to a specific direction.

Comment: It is certainly possible.  Suppose points on a unit sphere are $(x,y,z)$ with $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.  Then $Z$ can have any distribution you like on $[-1,1]$ (concentrate it near $0$ if you want to be close to the equator - a uniform distribution for $Z$ will give a uniform distribution on the sphere) and then take $\Theta$ uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi)$ so you can let $X=\sqrt{1-Z^2}\cos(\Theta)$ and $Y=\sqrt{1-Z^2}\sin(\Theta)$ to get a distribution symmetric around the $z$-axis.  If you want to change the direction of symmetry, rotate the result.

Comment: Awesome! I tried it on MATLAB and I see exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: If my comment answers your question, I will turn it into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly possible.

Suppose points on a unit sphere are $(x,y,z)$ with $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

Then $Z$ can have any distribution you like on $[−1,1]$ (concentrate it near $0$ if you want to be close to the equator; a uniform distribution for $Z$ will give a uniform distribution on the sphere)

and then take $\Theta$ uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi)$ so you can let $X=\sqrt{1-Z^2}\cos(\Theta)$ and $Y=\sqrt{1-Z^2}\sin(\Theta)$ to get a distribution symmetric around the $z$-axis.

If you want to change the direction of symmetry, rotate the result.